# PHP+PDO: Working MySQL Query with >10 rows always return 0 row (rowCount()==0)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the problem, that my following function

```
$theArray=$manageUsersInstance->listUserFahrgemeinschaften();
```

always returns 0 rows, but when using PHPMyAdmin there is always a result. 
The function always returns 0 when calling the function without parameters.

With parameters

```
$param = array('bfg.benutzer' => 1);
$theArray=$manageUsersInstance->listUserFahrgemeinschaften($param);
```

The function is Working

```
function listUserFahrgemeinschaften($param = null)
{
    if(isset($param)){
        foreach($param as $key => $value){

            $query_result = $this->link->query("SELECT     fg.id 'fg_id', ".
                    "fg.description 'fg_description', ".
                    "fg.created_by_benutzer 'fg_created_by_benutzer', ".
                    "fg.created_on 'fg_created_on', ".
                    "bfg.id 'bfg_id', ".
                    "bfg.fahrgemeinschaft 'bfg_fahrgemeinschaft', ".
                    "bfg.benutzer 'bfg_benutzer', ".
                    "bfg.is_admin 'bfg_is_admin', ".
                    "bfg.is_default 'bfg_is_default', ".
                    "bfg.freigeschaltet 'bfg_freigeschaltet' ".
                    "FROM cp_fahrgemeinschaft fg  ".
                    "INNER JOIN cp_benutzerfahrgemeinschaften bfg ".
                    " ON fg.id=bfg.fahrgemeinschaft WHERE $key = '$value'");                
        }
    }
    else {
        $query_result = $this->link->query("SELECT         fg.id 'fg_id', ".
                    "fg.description 'fg_description', ".
                    "fg.created_by_benutzer 'fg_created_by_benutzer', ".
                    "fg.created_on 'fg_created_on', ".
                    "bfg.id 'bfg_id', ".
                    "bfg.fahrgemeinschaft 'bfg_fahrgemeinschaft', ".
                    "bfg.benutzer 'bfg_benutzer', ".
                    "bfg.is_admin 'bfg_is_admin', ".
                    "bfg.is_default 'bfg_is_default', ".
                    "bfg.freigeschaltet 'bfg_freigeschaltet' ".
                    "FROM cp_fahrgemeinschaft fg  ".
                    "INNER JOIN cp_benutzerfahrgemeinschaften bfg ".
                    "ON fg.id=bfg.fahrgemeinschaft ORDER BY fg.id DESC");               
    }

    if($query_result==false)
    {
        return "Query failed! ".mysql_error()."\n";
    }

    $rowCount = $query_result->rowCount();

    if($rowCount == 1)
    {
        $result = $query_result->fetchAll();
    }
    else
    {
        $result = 0;                
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Is there any possibility that the resultset contains more than ONE row and after checking equality with ONE, you automatically go to the else clause where you are zeroing the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

İf you have a 10 record ,this if will be give problem

```
 if($rowCount == 1)//it must be : if($rowCount > 0)
        {
            $result = $query_result->fetchAll();
        }
        else
        {
            $result = 0;                
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been watching on that function too long that there was no chance to see it ... Hail to Manowar!!! ;-)

Comment: Hail from istanbul :)